# Silverlight + RIA and ADFS STS fails after some time

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, ria, adfs2.0

I'm creating a Silverlight interface using RIA services to access our data.

The application is protected using an ADFS login screen (configured using the "Identity and Access" tool in Visual Studio 2012).

Generally, everything works as expected:

- When accessing the host page I get redirected to the ADFS login page
- Upon login I get redirected back to the host page
- The RIA domain service can retrieve the ADFS credentials using `HttpContext.Current.User` thus making sure calls are being made for the correct user.
- RIA queries / invokes / etc work fine...

... for a while. I think they will work for about an hour or so (I haven't pinpointed the exact time yet) before things go bad.

When they do, a request to the RIA service is being redirected to the ADFS login page (I found that out using the IEs Developer Window - F12 - and the Network tab).

My initial thought is that the ADFS security token times out and the client needs to reauthenticate. However, I've set the token expiration time on ADSF to 6 hours, yet the problem persists.

It is important to note that the Silverlight application periodically calls the RIA service to check for new updates, so it shouldn't be some kind of "inactivity" timeout - as there is never any inactivity.

At this stage, I'm a bit out of ideas. Can anyone help?

*I don't know which parts of my code would be useful here - I will post what I can if someone requests it.*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a timeout of the SAM (Session Authentication Module). 
Have a look at [this Brock Allen's post](http://brockallen.com/2013/02/17/sliding-sessions-in-wif-with-the-session-authentication-module-sam-and-thinktecture-identitymodel/) and the [linked one](http://brockallen.com/2013/02/14/configuring-session-token-lifetime-in-wif-with-the-session-authentication-module-sam-and-thinktecture-identitymodel/)

Comment: While you are correct in that the exceptions are caused by SAM (the token expires), the solutions provided are of little help. Well, the latter one (increasing the token lifetime) is useful, but only up to a point - it doesn't actually solve the problem, only causes it to occur less often. I still need a way to either force the user to go to the ADFS sign-in page or in some other way handle the SL errors that are caused by SAM timeouts.